# inserting only in two columns of database using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have about 30 40 columns but only inserting in 2 columns to practice.

Right now this is how i am inserting into database.

**UsersTable.php**

```
public function createUser($data)
    {

        $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('users');
        $user = $usersTable->newEntity();

        $user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
        $user->first_name = $data['first_name'];


        $usersTable->save($user);
    }
```

and in the controller **UsersController.php**

```
function signUp()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $data['first_name']='test first name';
            $data['last_name']='test last name';
            $this->Users->createUser($data);
        }


        else{
            $this->viewBuilder()->Setlayout('signup');
        }
    }
```

This is going fine but i have a doubt that is this a good way to do this?.

What if i have to insert 15 columns so i have to mention every `entity` in the model like this ?

`$user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
 $user->first_name = $data['first_name'];`

Comment: no, patchEntity does the job for you https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities

Comment: sorry but i did not understand. i need to add it to the controller? also why to add the ` $_accessible`

Comment: I've told you in your other question already to read that chapter, so go and read the entity chapter. It explains the reason for $_accessible. Also why are you instantiating a users table object inside the object itself!? This doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: i have read that from that i have got this idea. Allow me to give you link from where i am following the tutorial. (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#inserting-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method used to patch the data into the entity so you don't have to do it by yourself: `patchEntity()`

`patchEntity` check for the passed array and assign the values to the correpsonding keys of the entity.

So instead of doing

```
$user = $usersTable->newEntity();
$user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
$user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
$usersTable->save($user);
```

you can simply do

```
$user = $usersTable->newEntity();
$usersTable->patchEntity($user, $data);
$usersTable->save($user);
```

as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities)

Even simplier you can do

```
 $user = $usersTable->newEntity($data);
 $usersTable->save($user);
```

usually `$data` comes from the request query son you don't even have to create the array yourself

in the controller:

```
$user = $usersTable->newEntity($this->request->data());
```

Comment: actually the array will then update all the records in the database. Also lets suppose i have `input name='f_name'` and in database there is `last_name` so thats why i am using array.

Comment: your solution works like a charm but i actually dont understand why we are creating entity here because when i was working in codeigniter and corephp i did not have to do this .

Comment: this is how cake works: Entities and Tables are separated objects. An entity is an abstraction of a record in a table. Table is the object deputate to take entities and tranform them into DB rows and vice-versa. You can create an entity and do a lot of manipulations on it but until you don't call Table->save($entity) nothing is saved in database.

Comment: Entity are handy when you have to manipulate a row at a time. If you have to do bulk updates (modify many records at the same time) you can use Table::updateAll(). Or you can use the query builder

Comment: Thank you for guiding me so well!

Comment: just the last question i am inserting record i have to also increment the id. Is this possible to do this from model

Comment: this is another question, and it's not so clear. Usually the DB has auto increment column. Consider opening a new question after doing your on researchs and trials

Comment: Thanks helping me so far