# Cakephp 3: update multiple columns at one time using save()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am following the book tutorial to update the current data

From the book

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articlesTable->get(12); // Return article with id 12

$article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';
$articlesTable->save($article);
```

This update the article title placed on id 12. But what if i have to update 6 7 fields. Like i am trying to do.

This is my code and its not updating except i mention every field individually.

```
public function updateUser($user_data,$id){

        $user = $this->get($id);

        $user->first_name = $user_data['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $user_data['last_name'];
        $this->save($user);
    }
```

also my array of `$user_data` have the keys exact as of the table columns i want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Use patch entity, it should look to something like this:

```
public function updateUser($user_data,$id){

    $user = $this->get($id);

    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user,$user_data);
    $this->save($user);
}
```

For more info: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validation-and-patchentity

Your controller is propabably called from updateUser.ctp, so try to use this as a standart for all your update actions:

```
public function edit($id)
{
     $user = $this->Users->get($id);
     if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
         $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user,$user_data);

         if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The {0} has been saved.', 'User '));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The {0} could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'User'));
        }
     }

     $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

You can obtain standart cake methods by using Cake Bake: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html

Comment: @Why to use `Users` because already we are saying $this which mean the same table or it is necessary?. Also what does this patch do? in documentation it is only saying that this validate the data.

Comment: actually what i was following the pattern of MVC all the database related things in the models. Isn't this a standard?

Comment: because this kind of method should be at the controller, not in the table.

Comment: Yes, so you call the patch entity from the controller, so the Users table handle the saving.

Comment: This updateUser method at the table is unecessary, all you need is to call the patch entity and save() from the controller.

Comment: See also [your own question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044697/inserting-only-in-two-columns-of-database-using-cakephp) where @arilia also told you about patching.

Comment: You need to read and understand the documentation. These are very basic and avoidable mistakes/questions.